# Drag/Drop from desktop into browser using GWT (Google Web Toolkit)

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag & drop files from a desktop into the browser using GWT?

As an example of usage, I'd like my GWT application to support functionality such as:

- image dragging from desktop to GWT app and GWT rendering it
- or dragging of a zip file and GWT displaying its content

I know this is possible using pure JavaScript (http://goo.gl/9u55Uj), but is it possible with the Google Web Toolkit native code?

So far I wasn't able to find any example of this on the web.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check [lib-gwt-file](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file) and maybe also [upload4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/upload4gwt/).